# Array.prototype is overriden

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The problem is my code is working under the assumption that the Array prototype object will not get modified by 1st party, 3rd party, or browser extension code. This is a dangerous assumption that cannot be made in JavaScript and it caused an avoidable CSO. How do I go about bulletproofing the code to prevent it from breaking in this circumstance?

Comment: I guess don't run your code in the browser? There is really no guarantee but *most likely* code shouldn't be tinkering with native prototypes.

Comment: Are you facing this problem right now or are you just trying to prevent the chance? Honestly, though this is a possibility, I have not faced or heard anyone face this problem in the real world at all.

Comment: What is your code doing that it would break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the nature of the Javascript. If you want to ensure that something is not overriden you must test expected behavior before using it. Let say you are using [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). Check its behavior, if it is not works like expected throw error.

```
var arr = [1, 2];
arr.push(3);
if (arr[2] !== 3) {
   throw "Push function is overriden!";
}
```